# Why are ruby request gems not formatting certs correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, x509certificate, rest-client

I am working on making some secure requests with certificates. In postman, I am able to include the cert and key and make the request without issue. But in Rails, with HTTParty, RestClient, and Net::HTTP it doesn't work. With HTTParty, it doesn't attach the cert/key even with the pem or ssl_ca_path class macros.

I am following the example set [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/2c72a2e77e2e87d25ff38feba0cf048d51bd5eca/README.md#ssl-client-certificates) to attach the cert/key to the request. When I throw a pry in to inspect the request.

It would appear to be a bug in the `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate` module as all the gems require an `OpenSSL::X509` object. But I can't find any reference to this on any site. Anyone have any insights as to why this would work in postman and javascript, but not Rails using any of the top gems to make requests?

With all the gems, I am setting the cert with `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('path/to/cert.pem'))` and the key with `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('path/to/key.pem'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Turns out `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate` wasn't parsing the entire certificate chain. After googling, found this post that addresses it by monkey patching `Net::HTTP` to accept more certificates for the chain

[Monkey Patch Net::HTTP](https://medium.com/in-the-weeds/net-http-and-x509-client-certificate-chains-and-monkey-patches-oh-my-ea5258dcb697)